# Reverse Geocoding by API: can't Google Maps be more precise?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have asked reverse geocoding for 121 place georges pompidou paris, france (where there is an excellent icecream :))

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=121+place+george+pompidou&sll=48.860921,2.351788&sspn=0.000745,0.002637&ie=UTF8&hq=121+place+george+pompidou&hnear=&ll=48.860568,2.351127&spn=0.000372,0.001318&t=h&z=20

It shows a marker at the beginning of the street instead of the middle of the street.

Can Reverse Geocoding by API be more precise (I have still to learn how to do so so I cannot code it yet) than this ?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that our data in this area isn't that granular.

You'll notice, in other areas, that data does exist for exact street numbers.

BTW - this is geocoding, not reverse geocoding :)

Comment: finally there's a stupid reason but google maps is also stupid in that case :)

Comment: could you correct your algorithm thanks see below explanation ;)

Answer (score 0):

Wow I found why: I forget "s" in georges ! But he guessed the right street why on earth can't it continue with the right street number that is quite irrational :)

Fantastic there is even a 3D panorama of the icecream shop !

http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=fr&geocode=&q=121+place+georges+pompidou,+paris&sll=46.75984,1.738281&sspn=6.427559,21.643066&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Place+Georges+Pompidou,+75004+Paris,+France&t=h&layer=c&cbll=48.860735,2.351243&panoid=DdrhIiQwG3tEWCya1Zg_IA&cbp=12,269.01,,0,21.31&ll=48.860735,2.351243&spn=0.000377,0.001321&z=20